# Implementing Code Problems

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, parameters, mef

I created a mapping application using arcGIS, C#, WPF, and MEF. I am actually new to all of these things which have made my project rather difficult. I have the application just the way I wanted and then ran into problems when I needed to implement it into the code.

Here is part of the code for my app:

```
[Export]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public partial class EsriMapView : DialogWindowBase
    {

        string Comments;
        string MeterNumMessage;
        GraphicsLayer _candidateGraphicsLayer;
        private static ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Projection.WebMercator _mercator =
                new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Projection.WebMercator();
        bool blnAddInformationClicked = false;
        bool blnEnterAddressClicked = false;
        string Specification = "Object Number: ";
        string addressCombined;
        string Object;
        string OComment;
        string OStreet;
        string OCity;
        string OState;
        string OZip;
        string OSpec;
        string GAttributes;
        string splitstring;
        int i = 0;
        string GStreet;
        string GObject;
        string GCity;
        string GState;
        string GZip;
        string GComment;
        string GSpec;
        Dictionary<string, string> Information = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Locator locatorTask = new Locator("http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Locators/TA_Streets_US/GeocodeServer");
        Locator AddlocatorTask = new Locator("http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Locators/TA_Streets_US_10/GeocodeServer");




        class arcObject
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Object_Num { get; set; }
            public string Comments { get; set; }
            public string Street { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string State { get; set; }
            public string Zip { get; set; }
            public string Spec { get; set; }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("Object Number: {0}, Comments: {1}, Street: {2}, City: {3}, State: {4}, Zip: {5}, Spec: {6}", Object_Num, Comments, Street, City, State, Zip, Spec);
            }
        }


        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;

        List<arcObject> arcObjects = new List<arcObject>();


        public EsriMapView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();  

         AddressGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            MeterLotGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            InformationGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            FindPortalGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            InstructionGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            AddPortalGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            UpdateObjectGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            UpdateInformationGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ViewInfoGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Envelope initialExtent =
                                     new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Envelope(
                             _mercator.FromGeographic(
                                     new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.MapPoint(-88.320026, 36.607915)) as MapPoint,
                             _mercator.FromGeographic(
                                     new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.MapPoint(-88.320026, 36.607915)) as MapPoint);

            initialExtent.SpatialReference = new SpatialReference(102100);



            _candidateGraphicsLayer = MyMap.Layers["CandidateGraphicsLayer"] as GraphicsLayer;
        }

        private void FindAddressButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool NoNulls;



            if ((Address.Text == "") | (City.Text == "") | (State.Text == "") | (Zip.Text == ""))
            {
                NoNulls = false;
                MessageBox.Show("All Fields Must Be Completed!");
            }
            else
            {
                NoNulls = true;
            }

            if (NoNulls)
            {
                Locator FindlocatorTask = new Locator("http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Locators/TA_Streets_US_10/GeocodeServer");
                FindlocatorTask.AddressToLocationsCompleted += FindLocatorTask_AddressToLocationsCompleted;
                FindlocatorTask.Failed += FindLocatorTask_Failed;
                AddressToLocationsParameters addressParams = new AddressToLocationsParameters();
                Dictionary<string, string> address = addressParams.Address;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address.Text))
                    address.Add("Street", Address.Text);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(City.Text))
                    address.Add("City", City.Text);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(State.Text))
                    address.Add("State", State.Text);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Zip.Text))
                    address.Add("ZIP", Zip.Text);

                FindlocatorTask.AddressToLocationsAsync(addressParams);
                PortalGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                AddressGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                InstructionGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

        }

        private void AddMarkerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InformationGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        }


        private void FindLocatorTask_AddressToLocationsCompleted(object sender, ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.AddressToLocationsEventArgs args)
        {
            _candidateGraphicsLayer.ClearGraphics();
            CandidateListBox.Items.Clear();

            List<AddressCandidate> returnedCandidates = args.Results;

            foreach (AddressCandidate candidate in returnedCandidates)
            {
                if (candidate.Score >= 80)
                {
                    CandidateListBox.Items.Add(candidate.Address);

                    Graphic graphic = new Graphic()
                    {
                        Symbol = AddressLayout.Resources["DefaultMarkerSymbol"] as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.Symbol,
                        Geometry = candidate.Location
                    };

                    graphic.Attributes.Add("Address", candidate.Address);

                    string latlon = String.Format("{0}, {1}", candidate.Location.X, candidate.Location.Y);
                    graphic.Attributes.Add("LatLon", latlon);

                    if (candidate.Location.SpatialReference == null)
                    {
                        candidate.Location.SpatialReference = new SpatialReference(4326);
                    }

                    if (!candidate.Location.SpatialReference.Equals(MyMap.SpatialReference))
                    {
                        if (MyMap.SpatialReference.Equals(new SpatialReference(102100)) && candidate.Location.SpatialReference.Equals(new SpatialReference(4326)))
                            graphic.Geometry = _mercator.FromGeographic(graphic.Geometry);
                        else if (MyMap.SpatialReference.Equals(new SpatialReference(4326)) && candidate.Location.SpatialReference.Equals(new SpatialReference(102100)))
                            graphic.Geometry = _mercator.ToGeographic(graphic.Geometry);
                        else if (MyMap.SpatialReference != new SpatialReference(4326))
                        {
                            GeometryService geometryService =
                                    new GeometryService("http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

                            geometryService.ProjectCompleted += (s, a) =>
                            {
                                graphic.Geometry = a.Results[0].Geometry;
                            };

                            geometryService.Failed += (s, a) =>
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Projection error: " + a.Error.Message);
                            };

                            geometryService.ProjectAsync(new List<Graphic> { graphic }, MyMap.SpatialReference);
                        }
                    }

                    _candidateGraphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(graphic);
                }
            }

            if (_candidateGraphicsLayer.Graphics.Count > 0)
            {
                CandidatePanelGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                CandidateListBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        void _candidateListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = (sender as ListBox).SelectedIndex;
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                MapPoint candidatePoint = _candidateGraphicsLayer.Graphics[index].Geometry as MapPoint;
                double displaySize = MyMap.MinimumResolution * 30;

                ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Envelope displayExtent = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Envelope(
                        candidatePoint.X - (displaySize / 2),
                        candidatePoint.Y - (displaySize / 2),
                        candidatePoint.X + (displaySize / 2),
                        candidatePoint.Y + (displaySize / 2));

                MyMap.ZoomTo(displayExtent);
            }
        }

        private void FindLocatorTask_Failed(object sender, TaskFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Locator service failed: " + e.Error);
        }
```

Now I the code above and the information received to be passed into the following code (Mapping Service):

```
[Description("ESRI Mapping Service")]
    [Export(typeof(IMappingService))]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
    public class EsriMappingService : IMappingService
    {
        #region Private Fields
        private readonly IUserInteractionService uis = AllianceApp.Container.GetExportedValue<IUserInteractionService>();
        #endregion

        #region IMapping Service Inteface


        void IMappingService.GetLatLong()
        {
            //TODO should look at reusing the implementation from the bing mapping service for getting current LatLong and should look at moving that out
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void IMappingService.ShowBlankMap(int? initialZoom, double? latitude, double? longitude)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void IMappingService.ShowPoints(string point, string pointTitle, string pointDetails, string pointLinkID, bool? zoomToBounds, bool? showLocation)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void IMappingService.ShowPoints(string point, string pointTitle, string pointDetails, string pointLinkID, bool? zoomToBounds)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void IMappingService.ShowPoints(bool? zoomToBounds)
        {
            this.ShowMap();
        }

        void IMappingService.ShowRoute(string start, string end, bool? showpoints, bool? showLocation)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void IMappingService.ShowRoute(string start, string end, bool? showpoints)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        double? IMappingService.gpsLat
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        double? IMappingService.gpsLong
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        #endregion

        private void ShowMap()
        {
            EsriMapView mv = new EsriMapView();
            uis.ShowDialog(mv);
        }
    }
}
```

The code was set up for me which has thrown me for a loop. I just need to be able to hard code a point onto the map using something like the line of code below, but it would probably need different parameters:

```
mapService.ShowPoints("1409 Fleetwood Dr, Murray, KY", "test Location", "Details", "foo", true);
```

I just need to know if I need to add anything to the EsriMapView(first piece of code).
I also had a ViewModel set up for me, but I also do not know how that would come into play. 
Here is what the ViewModel looks like as of right now:

```
[Export]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public class EsriMapViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

    }
```

There is a lot of code in my view, so if there is some other part of code that you need to see just let me know. Any help would be very appreciated. Like I said, I have never really done anything like this before. Thank-You.

Comment: you should remove the mvvm tag, cause thats all but not mvvm ;) your view is full of viewmodel code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use the EsriMapView object within you service, you will need to import it via MEF. You can either create an importing constructor or create a public property of the required type, and mark it with the Import attribute.

e.g.

```
 [Import]
    public EsriMapView MapView { get; set; }
```

Or if you need the Service within the EsriMapView class, then you would create a property in that class, importing the service.

e.g.

```
[Import]
        public IMappingService MapViewService { get; set; }
```

For an importing constructor, you would do the following

```
[ImportingConstructor]
    public EsriMapView([Import] IMappingService mappingService)
    {
    }
```

Ideally you would normally make use of Interfaces when marking items for import and export. Allowing you swap out different implementations for testing etc.

Read up on the MEF documentation for more information about this.

[MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/)